# Google Map doesn't show on Today Extension iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, today-extension

I want to show Google Map on Today Extension of my app but it doesn't work. I googled for a day but could not find a topic for my problem.

Below are my code and the result I got

```
import UIKit
import NotificationCenter
import GoogleMaps

class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(myKey)
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.868,
                                              longitude: 151.2086,
                                              zoom: 14)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), camera: camera)

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = camera.target
        marker.snippet = "Hello World"
        marker.map = mapView

        self.view.addSubview(mapView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: (@escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
        // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

        // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
        // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
        // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData

        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
    }

}
```

[image]

I think that Google is using some tricks to show the map on today extension like showing an image not the map because that map cannot interact.

Comment: You have posted a private API key in this question, still visible [in the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48218895/revisions). For your own security, **you must change this key with your provider**.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you can see the map correctly in the main iOS app.

You may be forgetting to configure the API key for the today extension `GMSServices.provideAPIKey(".........")`

Also, make sure the application identifier is correctly set in the google console. Today widgets have different app identifiers that the main app, so make sure you have both of them in the google console.